# OperationalError: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am getting error below in my django (1.6) uwsgi environment. I am using remote postgres using django-postgrespool. My uwsgi timeout is 180 seconds and my postgrespool configuration is below.

DATABASE_POOL_ARGS = {
    'max_overflow': 20,
    'pool_size': 2,
    'recycle': 300
}

I get the error intermittently and user see it as 500s. I don't understand how this is happens and whats wrong with the configuration.

Comment: What shows up in the logs when the user sees the 500 error?

Comment: what is your max_connections setting in postgresql.conf ?